# How to have a function repeat itself multiple times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

so I want to generate  random, floating-point numbers between 0 and 1 and calculate the mean. Then repeat this  times. I want to do a Histogram with this later.

This is what I came up with so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

#random float number between 0 and 1
x=np.random.random(n)

print(np.mean(x))

#building my function
def myFunction(n,m):
    for n in x:
        return(np.mean(x))

print(myFunction(5,10))
```

So of course this will only give me one mean value, and my question is how can I build my function to repeat itself  times?

Comment: What would be the point of calculating the mean multiple times?  You're passing the same parameter each time, so you're just going to get the same result.  Anyway, once you do a `return`, the function is *done* - no more loop iterations will take place.

Comment: I get n random numbers each time so each time I would need to calculate a new mean

Comment: A function can only return one time.

Comment: That's what loops are for.

Comment: But you're not getting different random numbers each time through the loop. It's processing the same random numbers each time.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any loops.

Instead of generating a random array of `n` elements `m`, times, make an `n x m` array and use numpy's API to take your mean along the second axis:

```py
import numpy
m = 10
n = 5

x = numpy.random.random(size=(n, m))
means = x.mean(axis=1)
```

Comment: I think size should be `(m, n)`.

Comment: @KellyBundy it can be either one, you just have to pick the correct axis along which to compute the means

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt is a bit off. You pass `n` to the function, but you also then do `for n in x`. So n is overwritten, but x is also a single number, so it won't iterate how you are wanting it to. For loops can be nested, so you can initialise two lists, one which will be the means of each run in `m`, and one which will store all the values in each run inside `m` to return the mean.

```
def myFunction(n,m):
    mean_list = []

    for _ in range(m):
        inner_list = []

        for i in range(n):
            inner_list.append(np.random.random())

        mean_list.append(np.mean(inner_list))

    return mean_list
```

This returns a list of means, `m` means to be exact. So

```
myFunction(5, 10)
```

returns (as an example)

```
[0.6635917645438433, 0.5569813806972684, 0.5869406453209447, 0.48729391271790945, 0.6276934115328581, 0.6109176360963581, 0.45357579860009095, 0.611056289890255, 0.15579494695767637, 0.5097066251736436]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the comments in the code below for an explanation:

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import random

#Your function should contain a loop:
def myFunction(n,m):
  # This loop is the "repeat M times" part. The variable "i"
  # will count 0 to M - 1, a total of "M" iterations
  for i in range(m):   
    #Everything inside here will run "M" times 
    x = np.random.random(n) # Here we generate N random numbers
    mean = np.mean(x) #Here is the mean
    
    #Print the means
    print("Iteration {} mean: {}".format(i, mean))

myFunction(5,10) #Call it with N = 5 and M = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because `return` ends the function, you would have to either return a list of some sort or data container (1). Another alternative would be to run an outside loop with the parameters that you want(2).

ex. 1

```
def mf(m, n):
    return np.mean(n)

data = []

for x in range(m):
    data.append([x, mf(m, n)])
```

2

```
def mf(m, n):
    data = []
    for x in range(m):
        data.append([x, np.mean(n)])
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your code.

First, since you created x outside of the function, it creates n random values just once and reuses the same x value resulting in the same mean.

Second, when you use return inside a for loop, it will stop the for loop and exit the function in the first iteration resulting in only one output.

A better way

```py
import numpy as np # numpy has random module
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def myFunction(n,m):
    list = []
    for i in range(m):
        x = np.random.rand(n)
        list.append(np.mean(x))
    return np.array(list)

# Even better way is to use list comprehension
def myFunction(n,m):
    list = np.array([np.mean(np.random.rand(n)) for i in range(m)])
    return list
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to create the random array in the loop, so you get different random numbers each time.

The loop should collect all the results into a list, and return the list. You can do this using a list comprehension.

```
def myFunction(n,m):
    return [np.mean(np.random(n)) for _ in range(m)]
```